# ARC Semantic Issue

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to objective c coding, please bear with me to ask if this is a simple question.

When I try to run the code below it says

```
NO visible @interface for 'SampleClass' declares the selector 'multiplyA:withB'
```

**Is it the wrong way to multiply two numbers in objective C?** I am unable to find the error.

This is the header file of the code

```
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

    @interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

    @property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

    @end

    @interface SampleClass : NSObject

    -(NSNumber *)multiplYA:(NSNumber *)a withB:(NSNumber *)b;

    @end
```

This is implementation file of the code

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
   {
               // Insert code here to initialize your application


               SampleClass *sampleClass = [[SampleClass alloc]init];
               NSNumber *a = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.5];
               NSNumber *b = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0];


               NSNumber *result = [sampleClass multiplyA:a withB:b];


               NSString *resultString = [result stringValue];
               NSLog(@"The product is %@",resultString);


          }

           @end


          @implementation SampleClass

          - (NSNumber *)multiplyA:(NSNumber *)a withB:(NSNumber *)b
      {
               float number1 = [a floatValue];
               float number2 = [b floatValue];
               float product = number1 * number2;
               NSNumber *result = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:product];
               return result;
       }
          @end
```

Comment: a simple typo.. offtopic for SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to provide declaration of `multiplyA:withB` method in your `@interface` section. Now it reads `-(NSNumber *)multiplYA:(NSNumber *)a withB:(NSNumber *)b;`. see the error? big Y. it must be small. Or otherwise - big Y inside `@implementation` section. In other words they should match

Comment: typo: `multiplyA:withB`  should be `multiplyA:withB:` ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's your capitalization in the header file. Change the header function title to read:

```
-(NSNumber *)multiplyA:(NSNumber *)a withB:(NSNumber *)b;
```